# strange way to boot the pc

Tags: boot, usb, 15.04

I have a laptop setup to dual boot windows 7 professional en Ubuntu 15.04

Whenever booting to Ubuntu using the grub screen i first see a purple screen. after a few seconds the screen turns off. After a while I force shut it down. When I turn it back on then I still see the purple screen but only for a second then see a black screen with message about usb descriptor file, afterwards it boots up normally.

The problem is when I reboot I have do this again that is force shutdown at the purple screen and boot again

Does anyone know what might be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Is this problem recent or this is happening after fresh installation ?

Comment: This problem is recent

Comment: Have you tried with Ubuntu recovery mode?

Comment: Yes I have noticed that I enter recovery mode and then resume boot it boots up normally of course if I reboot afterward I have the same problem? Is something else I can do in recovery mode to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see GRUB boot menu, select the Advanced Option for Ubuntu. And then select 'Ubuntu Recovery Mode'

[image]

This will bring you an utility that will help you to recover most of the common problem caused during booting.

Select a menu option and press Enter to use it:

- clean: Attempts to make free space on your file system. If your storage is full and this is causing some sort of problem, this can help free up space.
- dpkg: Repairs broken software packages. If a package failed to install properly and your system doesn’t work because of it, this may help.
- failsafeX: Boots your computer in a failsafe graphic mode. If there’s a problem with your Xorg graphical server configuration or graphics drivers and that’s causing your Ubuntu system to boot to a black screen or preventing the graphical desktop from loading properly, this can get you back to that graphical desktop.
- fsck: Performs a file system check, which scans the computer’s file systems for errors and automatically fixes them.
- grub: Updates the GRUB boot loader. If you could use the GRUB boot loader to get to this menu, this option probably won’t help.
- network: Enable networking, which is disabled by default in recovery mode.
- root: Leaves the menu and goes to a root shell prompt. From here, you can mount the file system in write-mode and run commands that may help fix problems with the system. You should only do this if you know what you’re doing — it’s a way to fix the problem by hand if you know how.

[image]

If Problem still persists **Reinstall your Ubuntu**

To do this, insert Ubuntu live DVD or pendrive and boot from it. Start installing Ubuntu. While doing this, Ubuntu should find your existing installtion and should give you option to reinstall it. Choose Option 'Reinstall Ubuntu', this will keep your files and programs as it is withtout any problem.

*(Though it's still good idea to keep backup of your important data, just in case)*

This should solve your problem. If it does not, there might be a problem with your hardware.

Hope this helps

Comment: From what I read in your answer I suppose 1,2 and 4 are what I can try but I wonder if there's any effect on the windows nstf partitions since it is a dual boot btw I notice that if I select resume it boots normally which option would you suggest to start with @Sourabh

Comment: I dont think that it will affect your windows partitions, about sequence of options i would go with 2  then (3) then 4 and finally 1, assuming my last method didnt work out.

Comment: OK @Sourabh I'll try that next time BTW why would 3 be necessary? I mean doesn't the fact that it boot mean that graphical configuration is fine or am I jumping to conclusions too quickly? I assume you put it between parentheses because that a possible cause

Comment: As per your problem description, you never see other than purple color and that might be indication of XOrg Starting but not able to continue due to some problem. Or let's put it into windows terms, even if one can see bootloading in windows and crashes after that, does not mean Display drivers are working fine. :)

Comment: So @Sourabh As per problem description after force shutdown at the purple screen it boot normally means that there may be display problem hmmm I'll definitely try your suggested sequence then

Comment: in the end i resinstalled ubuntu and it boots normally now with ubuntu 16.04